# Desktop title bar has disappeared on Juno

Tags: release-juno, wingpanel

The desktop title bar has disappeared on Juno. Does anyone have a clue how to restore that? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the command `wingpanel` in terminal?

Comment: Hi jena, I did this: 'To open the Applications Menu with the keyboard, press Superkey  + Spacebar. When the App Menu re-appeared so did the The Top Panel.' and the panel remained. Thanx.